# How to render a single post from my post list in my app built with React Native and Apollo?

Tags: javascript, react-native, blogs, apollo

So I am trying to build an app similar to a blog. And I am not sure how to render the single post that has been chosen to read.

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={ () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Unique')}>
  <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>{post.title}</Text>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

^This is the event that navigates me to the post I have clicked (not sure how to pass its props or id)

And this is the component I am redirected to:

```
class Page extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <ScrollView>
        <Query query={UniqueNews}>
          {({data, loading})=> {
            if(loading) return <Text>Loading</Text>;
            const {posts} = data;
            return posts.map(post=>
              <OneNews key={post.id} post={post} />
            )
          }}
        </Query>
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}

const UniqueNews = gql `query{
  posts{
    title
    author
    date
    id
    body
    image{
      url
    }
  }
}
`
```

OneNews =

```
<View style={styles.containerStyle}>
      <View style={styles.cardSectionStyle}>
        <Text>{title}</Text>
        <Text>{author}</Text>
        <Text>{body}</Text>
      </View>
</View>
```

When I render or navigate to that screen, every post is shown instead of the one I have tapped on. How do I set this up? My expected output is to just see one of the posts (being the chosen one by tapping on it) and render it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this:

First I will pass a param while navigating to the Unique component :

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={ () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Unique', {id: post.id})}>
    <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>{post.title}</Text>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

After that, I will simply make a conditional render inside that Unique component:

```
<ScrollView>
 <Query query={singleNews}>
    {({data, loading})=> {
       if(loading) return <Text>Loading</Text>;
        const {posts} = data;
          return posts.map(post=>
            {if(this.props.navigation.state.params.id===post.id)
              return <View>
               <OneNews key={post.id} post={post} />
              </View>}
            )}}
        </Query>
      </ScrollView>
```

And that's it.